# Rails - options_for_select with range and minimum/maximum methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, helper

I am building a filter form for my index page with some dropdown lists. For this purpose, I just need to get the min and max value from one of my model column. And I pass the name in my params from my view. Here is my code:

```
<%= form_tag twits_path, method: :get do %>
<%= select_tag :filter_by, options_for_select(["like", "retweet"]) %>
<%= select_tag :start, options_for_select(Twit.minimum(params[:filter_by])..10)%>
<%= select_tag :end, options_for_select(Twit.minimum(params[:filter_by])..10) %>
<%= submit_tag "Filter", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Minimum and Maximum are Class methods from ActiveRecord :

```
Model.minimum(column)
=> smallest value from this column

Model.maximum(column)
=> highest value from this column
```

I can't succeed in getting min and max value from my model. It tells me `PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function min() does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT MIN() FROM "twits"
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT MIN() FROM "twits"`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Post your Twit's minimum method too

Comment: are you sure `params` accepts arguments? I think it should be `params[:filter_by]` as a key not as an argument

Comment: @arieljuod I edited my post. Thanks!

Comment: @Kkulikovskis Thanks for the headup. I just updated my code but I still have an error. I also updated my post with the new error.

Comment: It looks like no column name is being passed to the final SQL MIN method. Is `params` empty at this point? If you load up a Rails console and try `Twit.minimum(:id)` does that work? What about with `"id"` (a String) instead?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the params hash to see what's in it? it looks like params[:filter_by] is empty, have you set a default value for params[:filter_by] the first time you enter that url?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I figured it out !